# Checking if input's characters match the ones given in Python

Tags: python, acronym

I'm in a Python course for beginners.
We have to create a code that turns input of maximum 6 words into an acronym.

Before creating an acronym, it has to check if the words contain only characters from given set, but I can't just check if it's in alphabet as we are using our local alphabet that has special characters (õ, ä, ö, ü).

```
def main():

    nr_of_words_limit = 6
    chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwõäöüxyz"

    def not_allowed_characters_check(text, chars):
        """This checks if all words in text only include characters from chars"""

    def acronym(text, chars, nr_of_words_limit): 
        """Creates acronym after checking for not allowed characters"""
```

So, in this case:

```
text = "Hello World!"
```

It would just say that text contains not allowed characters due to the exclamation mark.

How would I go about comparing if every letter in every word in text matches chars then?

Thanks for any help, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way is to check if the set of characters in the word is a subset of the alphabet using `set(word).issubset(alphabet)`. For example:

```
alpha_set = set("best") 
print set("test").issubset(alpha_set)
print set("testa").issubset(alpha_set)
```

prints:

```
True
False
```

[Example here](https://ideone.com/kEz0IV)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/regex.html#regex-howto) to check if every word in your text matches a certain pattern. The pattern in your case is that all characters in a word should be letters of the alphabet : uppercase **A-Z** as well as lowercase **a-z** (i assume from your example) and the letters **õäöü** ).

Learning how to use regular expressions might seem daunting for beginners but with a bit of practice you will find them very useful and efficient.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

import re

def check_allowed_chars(text):
    """
    """
    pattern = re.compile('[a-zA-Zõäöü]+$')
    words = text.split()
    for word in words:
        if not pattern.match(word):
            print('The text contains not allowed characters!')
            return
```